# Asp.net Select RadioButtonList using JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Hi I have a radio button list

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="lista_ragionevolezza" runat="server" 
 DataSourceID="EntityDataSource_ragionevolezza" 
 DataTextField="descrizione" DataValueField="id" 
 SelectedValue='<%# Bind("id_ragionevolezza") %>' 
 class="radioButtonScegli" />
```

and I want to select this in a Javascript function using JQuery for clearing a selection

```
var rbList=$("." + "radioButtonScegli");
```

using this class selector, but the code didn't work. What is the correct way to select this object?
Thanks

Comment: What didn't work? Have you tried [debugging your Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/988363/542251)?

Comment: Because if, for example, i try to find the length (rbl.rows.length) i have no results and an error "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Comment: Why would that element have a rows property? if you did rbl.length that'd work, but rows is not a valid DOM element. I think your getting your Server side and client side mixed up. Inspect the actual HTML and see how it is actually rendered.

Comment: You also don't need the `+` just do `var rbList=$(".radioButtonScegli");`

Comment: ususally i use a rows property in radiobuttonlist client side. I try rbl.length but i doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class is added to a container in which .Net is placing those inputs.
Something like this should work:
`$(".radioButtonScegli").find(':radio');`

For clearing selection:

`$('.radioButtonScegli').find(':radio').prop('checked',false);'`

Answer (score 0):

**By ID**

```
var radiolist= $('input:radio[id$="lista_ragionevolezza"]');
```

**By class**

```
var radiolist= $('input:radio[class="radioButtonScegli"]');
```

or just `$('.radioButtonScegli')`

to make checked/unchecked you can use either `attr` or `prop`

```
$('.radioButtonScegli').find(':radio').attr('checked',false);

$('.radioButtonScegli').find(':radio').prop('checked',false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to not use the class selector, but the Client Id, because your javascript variable would change if you have more the 1 object which has the class `radioButtonScegli`.

Try selecting it this way:

```
var rbList = $('#<%=lista_ragionevolezza.ClientID%>')
```

This way `rbList` will only contain this one RadiobuttonList. And since this is an element containing 1 to n checkboxes, you need to iterate over each item to uncheck it:

```
rbList.each(function (i, chkbox){
    if($(chkbox).is(":checked")) {
        $(chkbox).removeAttr("checked");
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the ID of object:

```
var rblist = $("#lista_regionevolezza");
```

Comment: Why? the class is perfectly valid?

Comment: Also depending on how the ID's are configured in .Net that may not work.

Comment: Infact it don't work. I can't use the instruction getElementByName because I am in a FormView that change mode